# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findall' of null" in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Hi I am beginner in ionic.I already create an sample project which run perfectly in browser. But when I want to display in ios simulator by using cli command "ionic cordova run ios -l -c" it show an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findall' of null". Please suggest some solution so that I can overcome that problem. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WntPT.png)

Comment: Do you have a function or variable called "findall" and are you trying to update your view according to that value ?

Comment: sorry there has no findall function

Comment: Problem is I can see the build 2/3 times in ios simulator but problem is after the next time when I "ionic cordova run ios -l -c" it show error

Comment: the picture you uploaded is about android build failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it is similar to missing content of config.xml

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2623

Check the files if there is any missing content... I got it messed up with amending the file during run ...

Comment: Please tell me what I can do to solve the issue because I am beginner in Ionic2

Comment: If this is your issue, than either you place back the content into the file how it was. I think ionic puts under git immediately  the code what you generate, so you can check the previous version there. Or you just generate the prject again and being careful not to amend the file during run/build/etc...

Answer (score 0):

first check your config.xml, there may be missing or you can copy from other similar projects.